# About shared objects

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, shared-objects

Can we use or access shared object stored in another system?
I'm storing some data in shared object in one system can i access that shared object data from another system?

I think Shared objects are stored in local machine. Can we give the path to (specified system ie server)where the shared objects will store, and can we access that object through same path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. getLocal will only access the local filesystem, while getRemote is only for connecting to a flash media server (or equivalent).

Comment: What is the flash media server?

Comment: flash media server is a media server by adobe . FMS mainly used for video streaming, video on demand, data broadcasting etc. FMS use Real time message protocol(RTMP) . There are different type of fms used, red5, wowsa , SFS, sfs is mainly used for multiplayer game development.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the second argument of `SharedObject.getLocal()` method to the path where the shared object is stored. [flash.net.SharedObject.getLocal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for provided link I think getRemote() method will be usefull.. instead of getLocal()?